# VBScript Issue + I am trying to make it work on Windows XP

Tags: function, debugging, vbscript

```
state = 1
While state = 1
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    Set colProcessList = GetObject("Winmgmts:").ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process")
    Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        if objProcess.Name = "server.exe" And objProcess.Name = "cmd.exe" then
            vFound = True
        End if
    Next
    If vFound = True then
        wscript.sleep 10000
    Else
        Dim strArg, strArgs
        strArg = "pskill /accepteula cmd.exe"
        strArgs = "%windir%\psexec /accepteula \\server test.exe"
        oShell.Run strArg & oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
        wscript.sleep 10000
    End If
    vFound = False
Wend
```

Please help me run this script properly, what I am trying to do is, if the 'server.exe' and 'cmd.exe' is not found in process, run the Dim strArg and strArgs.

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? Do you get an error?

Comment: ---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\testing.vbs
Line: 17
Char: 36
Error: Expected end of statement
Code: 800A0401
Source:  Microsoft VBScript compilation error

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error is that you're making a nested call to the `Run` method here:

```
oShell.Run strArg & oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

To make this work you must put the parameter list of the nested call in parentheses:

```
oShell.Run strArg & oShell.Run(strArgs, 0, false)
```

However, it's not quite clear to me what you're trying to achieve here. Why are you concatenating the return value of one `Run` call with the command string of another `Run` call? Are you perhaps trying to run both commands in parallel? If so, you'd just have to do this:

```
oShell.Run strArg, 0, False
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, False
```

To run the commands sequentially, wait for each command to return:

```
oShell.Run strArg, 0, True
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, True
```

Comment: the way u suggested works :) but still it's not working as i want it to :(
i want it to run `strArg` first and then `strArgs`

Comment: Its running perfectly.. :)